Unable to test a language recognition model
I have a dataset of sentences in 4 different languages and I want a model that's able to recognize given a test sentence the language of this sentence.
Here's my code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import json
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# getting data from JSON file
with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Data preprocessing
all_sentences = []
all_labels = []
for lang, sentences in data.items():
    all_sentences.extend(sentences)
    all_labels.extend([lang] * len(sentences))

# Creation of vocabulary
vocab = set()
for sentence in all_sentences:
    words = sentence.split()
    vocab.update(words)

# Mapping words to index and vice versa
word_to_ix = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(vocab)}
ix_to_word = {i: word for word, i in word_to_ix.items()}

# Mapping language labels to index and vice versa
label_to_ix = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(set(all_labels))}
ix_to_label = {i: label for label, i in label_to_ix.items()}

# Conversion of sentences into index, with management of unknown words
UNK_IDX = len(vocab)
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 200

def sentence_to_indices(sentence):
    indexed_sentence = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        indexed_sentence.append(word_to_ix.get(word, UNK_IDX))
    # Rembourrage ou troncature pour avoir une longueur maximale fixe
    if len(indexed_sentence) > MAX_SEQ_LENGTH:
        indexed_sentence = indexed_sentence[:MAX_SEQ_LENGTH]
    else:
        indexed_sentence += [UNK_IDX] * (MAX_SEQ_LENGTH - len(indexed_sentence))
    return indexed_sentence

indexed_sentences = [sentence_to_indices(sentence) for sentence in all_sentences]
indexed_labels = [label_to_ix[label] for label in all_labels]

class LanguageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sentences, labels):
        self.sentences = sentences
        self.labels = labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sentences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return torch.tensor(self.sentences[idx]), torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])

dataset = LanguageDataset(indexed_sentences, indexed_labels)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

class LanguageClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(LanguageClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim * MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.embedding(x)
        flattened = embedded.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Aplatir les tenseurs
        output = torch.relu(self.fc1(flattened))
        output = self.fc2(output)
        return output

EMBEDDING_DIM = 50
HIDDEN_DIM = 128
OUTPUT_DIM = len(label_to_ix)
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
NUM_EPOCHS = 10

model = LanguageClassifier(len(vocab) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

# model training
for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    model.train()
    total_correct = 0
    total_samples = 0
    running_loss = 0.0

    for sentences, labels in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(sentences)
        loss = loss_function(output, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        _, predicted = torch.max(output, 1)
        # Update the running total of correct predictions and samples
        total_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        total_samples += labels.size(0)
        running_loss += loss.item()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{NUM_EPOCHS}, Loss: {running_loss}")
    # Calculate the accuracy for this epoch
    accuracy = 100 * total_correct / total_samples
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}: Accuracy = {accuracy:.2f}%')

# saving the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'language_classifier_model.pth')

def predict_language(model, sentence):
    model.eval()
    indexed_sentence = [word_to_ix.get(word, UNK_IDX) for word in sentence.split()]
    tensor_sentence = torch.tensor(indexed_sentence).unsqueeze(0)
    output = model(tensor_sentence)
    _, predicted_idx = torch.max(output, 1)
    return predicted_idx.item()

def test_model(test_sentence):
    model = LanguageClassifier(len(vocab) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load("language_classifier_model.pth"))
    predicted_idx = predict_language(model, test_sentence)
    predicted_language = list(data.keys())[predicted_idx]
    print(f"Phrase: '{test_sentence}', Langue prédite: {predicted_language}")

# test the model with a french sentence
test_sentence = "Votre modèle fonctionne-t-il bien ?"
test_model(test_sentence)

But I have the following error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 138
    136 # Teste le modèle avec une phrase donnée
    137 test_sentence = "Votre modèle fonctionne-t-il bien ?"
--> 138 test_model(test_sentence)

Cell In[1], line 132
    130 model = LanguageClassifier(len(vocab) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
    131 model.load_state_dict(torch.load("language_classifier_model.pth"))
--> 132 predicted_idx = predict_language(model, test_sentence)
    133 predicted_language = list(data.keys())[predicted_idx]
    134 print(f"Phrase: '{test_sentence}', Langue prédite: {predicted_language}")

Cell In[1], line 125
    123 indexed_sentence = [word_to_ix.get(word, UNK_IDX) for word in sentence.split()]
    124 tensor_sentence = torch.tensor(indexed_sentence).unsqueeze(0)
--> 125 output = model(tensor_sentence)
    126 _, predicted_idx = torch.max(output, 1)
    127 return predicted_idx.item()

File c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

Cell In[1], line 77
     75 embedded = self.embedding(x)
     76 flattened = embedded.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Aplatir les tenseurs
---> 77 output = torch.relu(self.fc1(flattened))
     78 output = self.fc2(output)
     79 return output

File c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File c:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py:116, in Linear.forward(self, input)
    115 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 116     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x250 and 10000x128)

I tried several things but I doesn't work thanks for your help.
I tried changing the dimension values in the LanguageClassifier for self.embedding and self.fc1.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

This is a common error when a shape mismatch is occurring in a nn.Linear:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x250 and 10000x128)

The first shape corresponds to the input, and the second is the shape of your linear layer, likely the first one you defined. We can check: your fc1 is defined as embedding_dim * MAX_SEQ_LENGTH x hidden_dim ie. 50*200 x 128. This fits with the 2nd shape in the error message. On the other hand, the received tensor is shaped (1,250). So your first linear layer should be 250 x 128, not 1000 x 128.
